# Selenium Send_keys method send the path multiple times

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have Selenium code which support to send pictures as below

```
photos = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//*[contains(text(), 'Create Post')]/parent::*/parent::*/parent::*/parent::*//input")

photos.sendKeys(
    "C://Users/1.PNG")
photos.send_keys(
    "C://Users/2.jpg")
photos.send_keys(
    "C://Users/3.PNG")
photos.send_keys(
    "C://Users/4.jpg")
```

However, it worked but in each line it keep send the previous path again so in picture number 2 it send 1 & 2 and in picture number 3, it send 1,2 & 3 and so on.

Comment: Do you want all the pictures??? from your question it seems you want to send each one on its own...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uploading multiple files using sendkeys() method try this:

```
    WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your_xpath"));
    String uploadFilePath1 = "C:/file1.PNG";
    String uploadFilePath2 = "C:/file2.PNG";
    String uploadFilePath3 = "C:/file3.PNG";
    inputField.sendKeys(uploadFilePath1 + "\n " + uploadFilePath2 + "\n " + uploadFilePath3);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with some modification as below: WebElement inputField = driver.find_element_by_xpath("your_xpath");
    String uploadFilePath1 = "C:/file1.PNG";
    String uploadFilePath2 = "C:/file2.PNG";
    String uploadFilePath3 = "C:/file3.PNG";
    inputField.send_keys(uploadFilePath1 + "\n " + uploadFilePath2 + "\n " + uploadFilePath3);

Answer (score 0):

Using Java, you could try something like this:

```java
driver.findElement(By.id("id1")).sendKeys("path1");
driver.findElement(By.id("id2")).sendKeys("path2");
driver.findElement(By.id("id3")).sendKeys("path3");
```

Comment: I tried to use sendKeys() but it did not work for me, xpath selector was used

Comment: Did you test your answer before posting?